# Have Android app auto refresh when not in use

Tags: android, android-asynctask, refresh, auto-update

I have a weather app that uses an AsyncTask to retrieve information and display it to the user. What I want to do is give the user a notification every time I receive information about severe weather, so my app needs to automatically refresh and perform the network operations when the user is not using the app and when the phone is not being used. Preferably, I can set the interval in which the app updates itself. Is there any way to do this? I've looked online but I can't seem to find anything, or I'm not using the right wording. Any links to tutorials would be great. Thanks!

Comment: That is a typical use case for [Push Notifications](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Timer Task for fixed intervals and may be http://iamvijayakumar.blogspot.com/2012/07/android-timertask.html can help.